# zf2 setup on ubuntu 13.10 with Apache virtual host

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, zend-framework2, virtualhost

I am configuring Zend application (ZF2) in ubuntu 13.10. Following the steps below :

1. Place code in `/var/www/` with name `zfapp`

Virtual host config :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName zfapp.com DocumentRoot /var/www/zfapp/ 

  <Directory /> 
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All 
  </Directory> 

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log 

   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, 
   # alert, emerg. 
   LogLevel warn 
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined 

</VirtualHost>
```

1. Creating virtual host for it in `/etc/hosts`

   127.0.0.1   zfapp.com
2. Add file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/zfapp.cof`
3. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
4. `sudo a2ensite zfapp.conf`
5. `sudo service apache2 restart`

However when I browse to the site (`zfapp.com/api/user/auth`); It gives following error:

> **Not Found**
>   The requested Url `/api/user/auth` was not found on this server

I have a javascript MVC project in which i am using PHP as server side language.

Here is the project directory structure:

ProjectDir
   javascriptMVC folder-> models/controllers jsfiles
   api folder -> Zend project

I have made a symbolic link **api** which points to `api/public` inside **javascriptMVC** directory, which i use in AJAX calls to PHP server. like `/api/user/auth`. The same structure works on old Ubuntu machine.

I think it has something to do with Apache configuration; or perhaps I have to set any Alias?

Comment: Can you hit just `zfapp.com`?

Comment: Show your routes configuration.

Comment: routs ? you mean etc/hosts ?

Comment: i have zfapp.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/zfapp.conf                      <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName zfapp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/zfapp/
     <Directory />

              Options FollowSymLinks

              AllowOverride All
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

     # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
     # alert, emerg.
     LogLevel warn

     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks all,

I have found the problem.

In apache 2.4.6 and ubuntu 13.10 we need to update apache2.conf
change in

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

with

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and create your virtual host file something like this,

```
<VirtualHost zfapp.com:80>
    ServerName zfapp.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/zfapp/index

    <Directory /var/www/zfapp/index>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have found solution from: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/423514/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-virtual-host

by the way, thanks @Bilal , @jmleroux

Comment: If you have still 500 error with this configuration, as I had, try enable module rewriting: sudo a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 2):

Without code, it's hard to diagnose...

Maybe a problem of url rewriting :

Did you enable mod_rewrite ?

Did you set `AllowOverride All` ?

Comment: YES, its enabled using (sudo a2enmod rewrite)

Comment: Maybe it's the new Apache : 13.10 comes with apache 2.4. You need `Require all granted`

Comment: "Without code, it's hard to diagnose" Then don't; This isn't an answer; but rather two questions that should be comments.

Answer (score 0):

@Bilal probably means your *ZF2* routing configuration: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html